# vidalia fails to anonymize despite showing green onion

Tags: networking, proxy, tor, polipo

Here's what I have done:

```
sudo apt-get install vidalia
```

and it has been installed after that I've set the proxy settings in network to `localhost:8118` and applied it system wide; however, when I want to install a package via apt-get an error logs saying:  `Unable to connect to localhost:8118: [IP: 127.0.0.1 8118]`

Also tor check is not working because I can't connect to the internet at all when the proxy option is applied.

The main propose of using tor here is to use it with terminal.

Update: I've already applied the configuration to the polipo, FYI.

Answer (score 1):

In your question update you write that you applied the configuration to [Polipo](http://www.pps.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~jch/software/polipo/). Tor uses either Polipo or [Privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org/). Privoxy is currently the default proxy and listens by default at port 8118.

Polipo listens at a different port. It uses 8123. So you should change your settings to `127.0.0.1:8123`. If everything else is set up correctly it will work now.

Comment: Wrong answer. I have found the solution myself but that was a long time ago. I think they have completely fixed the issue by now.